# Сортировка фотографий по цветам

Tags: сортировка, цвета

Возникла идея отсортировать фотографии по цвету. Всё сводится к определению основного цвета и дальнейшей фильтрации, но насчёт последнего возник вопрос. Если сортировать просто по значениям RGB, то выходит сортировка от темных тонов к светлым. А это не совсем то, что нужно. Хотелось бы, чтобы оттенки одного цвета находились рядом друг с другом и в результате получалось что-то вроде градиента. Как это реализовать?

[image: Пример сортировки по каналам RGB]

Comment: [Невероятно трудная задача сортировки цветов](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/30/colour-sorting/) (англ).

Comment: RGB не очень подходит для распределения по цветам. Конвертируйте RGB цвета в [LAB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAB) (формулы для конвертации гуглятся), там параметры a и b как раз отвечают за цвет, L - за "светлоту". Вот для сортировки по цвету и используйте a и b.